# Replace current match with its own text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to replace matched hyperlinks with their link text. That is:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

becomes

`Stack Overflow`

I'm trying:

```
$("table.ms-listviewtable a:nth-child(4)").replaceWith($(this).text())
```

but get a JavaScript error.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"this" isn't what you expect at the time you're executing it.

Something like this should do:

```
$("table.ms-listviewtable a:nth-child(4)").each(function()
{
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: You are missing a point (literally!), but otherwise it's exactly the same thing I would have suggested, too.